# How to configure AWS Glue to access SAP data via pyodata API and an established VPC?

Tags: odata, aws-glue, amazon-vpc, sap-gateway

I'm trying to use the pyodata API to fetch data from SAP services, which I then want to process with AWS Glue. The SAP system is on a private network but connected to my AWS through a VPC and TGW. I already have a functional VPC set up in AWS. How can I configure AWS Glue to access this data using the pyodata API and my VPC?

Answer (score 0):

Glue won't be able to use pyodata directly. But you can load the data into the glue job using the pyodata package and then convert the results to a Glue Dynamic Frame.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-libraries.html

Comment: Hi Leeroy, my question was more so around if I need to provision any more resources or whether I need to configure anything additional in Glue in order to ensure connectivity to SAP within my VPC, WHILST using pyodata. I understand that glue and the dynamic frame doesn't have built in support for pyodata and that I will have to install the package first.

Comment: While I know how to connect to JDBC on-prem, im not sure about doing the same with pyodata. My suggestion would be to use pyodata on EC2 and dump the data in S3, then use Glue to do the transformation you require by reading it from S3. This link may also help: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/how-to-access-and-analyze-on-premises-data-stores-using-aws-glue/